WSL: Processing fstab with mount -a failed
When entering in my archlinux WSL with the command wsl -d Arch after a fresh install, (I completed a base install of arch linux in virtualbox. By exporting it as a compressed tar file, transferred it in my windows machine and imported it using the wsl --import command). It first prints 'Processing fstab with mount -a failed.' in the console and then enters the bash shell of the arch distribution.

First of all why is this happening?
How to fix this?
Is it any serious problem?


The system is running mount -a as part of its normal start-up process and failing. That usually means one of the lines of /etc/fstab has a problem. Since it interrupts the boot process and drops you into a rescue shell, it complicates the normal use of the system. So in some sense it is a fairly serious problem, but it might be easy to fix.
From your installation method, I would guess that the original base install in VirtualBox had some separate filesystem (perhaps /boot?) that either doesn't exist in WSL, is now a part of the root filesystem, or now has a different filesystem UUID.
You should read the contents of the /etc/fstab file, and correct any lines that need changes or are no longer applicable in the WSL system environment.
You can compare the contents of /etc/fstab to /proc/mounts.
If you find non-comment lines in /etc/fstab that don't have a matching line in /proc/mounts, try mounting them manually one by one and see what kind of error you'll get.
If the line refers to a filesystem by UUID, use blkid or lsblk -o +uuid to view the actual filesystem UUIDs in the WSL environment, and correct the UUID in /etc/fstab as necessary.
If the line refers to a filesystem that existed in VirtualBox but is now contained in the root filesystem in WSL, you can comment out or delete the line from /etc/fstab.
The /proc/mounts may contain lines that don't exist in /etc/fstab: these are usually virtual filesystems that are automatically mounted to standard location by system startup scripts. You can ignore those.
If you need more help than this, please edit your question to show the current contents of your /etc/fstab and the output of lsblk -o +uuid or blkid. (Please don't add them as a comment or as a non-answer Answer post; here in StackExchange, we like all the information relevant to the question right at the top.)

Yes! I commented all the lines in /etc/fstab because their corresponding filesystem partitions no longer exist in WSL and after a reboot it worked!
